# ESD Protection for flyback diode - Relay circuit

Tags: relay, esd, circuit-protection, flyback, tvs

I am designing a board to accommodate relay and flyback diode with IO connector in a PCB. The low side driver of relay will be present in another PCB. Both the boards will be connected through wires(12V supply and Drain of low side driver). Please refer attached image to understand the schematic.
[image]
I understand that when the relay board is not connected to anything, and when human interfaces with relay board, there are possibilities for ESD event across flyback diode which can damage the diode.
But I do not understand that when human touches the input connector, how ESD high potential develops across flyback diode since anode and cathode of flyback diode is floating when the board is not connected anywhere.
If the anode of flyback diode is connected to GND, then it is easy to assume that high potential developed across flyback diode. When both the pins of flyback diode is floating, how high potential develops across diode?
If high voltage developed, will the TVS diode across flyback diode protect the circuit?

Comment: Sorry.. Image added now.

Comment: Instead of all that messing around with a TVS, just make the FB a zener diode where the zener voltage is higher than the relay's maximum coil voltage.

Comment: In my opinion, **there is no need for ESD protection**. ESD protection is needed to protect sensitve transistors or ICs, you have a relay coil which is **insensitive to ESD**. The flyback diode also isn't sensitive enough so that it must be protrected. But please prove me wrong and explain what damage the ESD will do.